# On a motor after a continuous input of a certain amount of time

Tags: arduino-mega

I would like to produce an output after a constant input is detected for a certain amount of time. Below is a simple code of what I am trying to do minus the time factor. Can someone help me on how to code out the duration of an input occurrence?  i.e.

```
if (sensorValue > threshold);
    //if this occurs for more than 4 hours, then
    digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
```

Comment: A constant input would be an analog value between two bounderies. Not just a check if it is above a threshold. Use millis for timing, it can count up to 50 days. The blink-without-delay uses an interval, but it explains the use of millis: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay Provide a minimal but complete working sketch please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store the state of the last readings and do something like this:

```
    //Off-loop:
    bool state_changed = false;
    unsigned long time_in_state = 0;
    unsigned long last_reading = 0;

    //On-loop:
    if (sensorValue > treshold && !state_changed) {
        time_in_state += millis() - last_reading;
        last_reading = millis();
    }
    else {
        state_changed = true;
        time_in_state = 0;
    }

    if (time_in_state > TIME_REQUIRED) {
      digitalWrite (3, HIGH);
    }
```